# Where are variables set in cmake?

Tags: cmake

I'm having trouble with a `make` process, so after some reading I was led to the CMakeLists.txt file, which as I understand, is a configuration of sorts for cmake (which in turn generated makefiles).

So, I'm looking through a CMakeLists.txt file.  I'm seeing references to something called ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR} but it doesn't seem to be declared anywhere in the file.  Where is it declared?

Answer (score 0):

There are many *automatic* variables, which are set by CMake or by other means. See [variables documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/manual/cmake-variables.7.html).